# Unexpected end of JSON input when using cucumber-html-reporter with Nightwatch-Cucumber

Tags: javascript, selenium, cucumber, nightwatch.js

I use `Nightwatch-Cucumber` to automate my end2end tests and want to create a cucumber html report after test execution with `cucumber-html-reporter`, but I get an error while report generation by `cucumber-html-reporter`:

```
Unable to parse cucumberjs output into json: 'reports/cucumber.json' SyntaxError: reports/cucumber.json: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.readFileSync (/Users/GRme/projects/e2e-web-tests/node_modules/jsonfile/index.js:69:17)
```

And I don't know why my generated `cucumber.json` is invalid.

I use the following versions:

```
"cucumber-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
"nightwatch": "^0.9.16",
"nightwatch-cucumber": "^7.1.10",
```

This is my config in `nightwatch.conf.js`:

```
require('nightwatch-cucumber')({
  cucumberArgs: [
      '--tags', '@run',
      '--require', 'timeout.js',
      '--require', 'hooks.js',
      '--require', 'features/step_definitions',
      '--format', 'pretty',
      '--format', 'json:reports/cucumber.json',
      'features']
});
```

And this is the `hooks.js`, where my cucumber html report generation is executed:

```
const {client} = require('nightwatch-cucumber');
const {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');
var reporter = require('cucumber-html-reporter');

var options = {
  theme: 'bootstrap',
  jsonFile: 'reports/cucumber.json',
  output: 'reports/cucumber_report.html',
  reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
  launchReport: false,
  //ignoreBadJsonFile: true,
  name: 'NIKITA end2end tests',
  brandTitle: 'NIKITA end2end tests',
  storeScreenShots: true,
  metadata: {
//    "App Version": "0.0.1",
//    "Test Environment": "AAT",
//    "Browser": "Chrome XXX",
//    "Platform": "Mac OS X",
  }
};

defineSupportCode(({Before, After}) => {
  Before(function() {
    client.maximizeWindow();
  });

  After(function() {
    reporter.generate(options);
  });
});
```

My generated and apparently invalid cucumber.json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "keyword": "Feature",
    "line": 1,
    "name": "only a test feature",
    "tags": [],
    "uri": "/Users/GRme/projects/e2e-web-tests/features/testFeature.feature",
    "elements": [
      {
        "keyword": "Scenario",
        "line": 4,
        "name": "only a test Scenario",
        "tags": [
          {
            "line": 3,
            "name": "@run"
          }
        ],
        "id": "only-a-test-feature;only-a-test-scenario",
        "steps": [
          {
            "arguments": [],
            "keyword": "Before",
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 1
            },
            "hidden": true,
            "match": {
              "location": "/Users/GRme/projects/e2e-web-tests/hooks.js:24"
            }
          },
          {
            "arguments": [],
            "keyword": "When ",
            "name": "\"1\" seconds waiting",
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 2615
            },
            "line": 5,
            "match": {
              "location": "/Users/GRme/projects/e2e-web-tests/features/step_definitions/abstractStepDefinition.js:10"
            }
          },
          {
            "arguments": [],
            "keyword": "After",
            "result": {
              "status": "passed",
              "duration": 4
            },
            "hidden": true,
            "match": {
              "location": "/Users/GRme/projects/e2e-web-tests/hooks.js:28"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "id": "only-a-test-feature"
  }
]
```

Generating the Cucumber Html Report via Jenkins with the `Cucumber Reports Plugin` runs successful.

So, how can I solve my problem and which framework (`Nightwatch-Cucumber` or `cucumber-html-reporter`) is the reason? And what is the invalid part of my generated `cucumber.json`?

Comment: The JSON you posted is valid. Check the file to make sure there isn't something extra, like a BOM character.

Comment: That is really the reason for the problem. I opened and saved the `cucumber.json` in an editor and saved it as an UTF-8 file without BOM and now it runs. So the problem should be `Nightwatch-Cucumber` that creates and writes this file. How can I ensure to delete these BOMs in JavaScript? Is there any Node.js library to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `Event Handler`. I put the Cucumber report generation in such a Event Handler function for the event `AfterFeatures` and it works perfect for me.

More information you can find [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/event_handlers.md).

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate cucumber html report in a separate step of test execution. For example if you are using npm script use a separate npm script to generate the report. The problem with your approach is that in Cucumber.js global `After` hook the report is not created yet. That's why you are getting such an error. I suggest to use a separate node.js script to run cucumber-html-reporter.